# Get scale unit at cart

Tags: symfony, shopware, shopware6

I need the scale unit at my cart to show it at the frontend, but I do not get it.
I tried by a subscriber and to load the product, but I do not get the selected scale unit.

```
  public function onLoadCart(OffcanvasCartPageLoadedEvent $event)
  {
    foreach ($event->getPage()->getCart()->getLineItems() as $item) {
      $product = $this->productRepository->search(
        new Criteria(
          [
            $item->getId()
          ]
        ),
        $event->getContext()
      )->first();

      dd($product);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term scale unit offset me a little at first. I assume you are looking for the ProductUnit. [The ProductUnit is an association](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/master/src/Core/Content/Product/ProductDefinition.php#L191), and you need to add this to your criteria.

```
public function onLoadCart(OffcanvasCartPageLoadedEvent $event)
  {
    foreach ($event->getPage()->getCart()->getLineItems() as $item) {
      $criteria = new Criteria(
          [
              $item->getId()
          ]
      );
      $criteria->addAssociation('unit');

      $product = $this->productRepository->search(
        $criteria,
        $event->getContext()
      )->first();

      dd($product);
    }
  }
```